# How to get the days from the post date to the current date in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, web, content-management-system

I have a wp website I am getting date of the post by the help of
`get_the_date()`

I want it to show days instead date.

means if the post wast was made on "June 8, 2022" then it should show days
how long its been posted of the post till the current date.

please help me to achive it.
Thanks

Comment: Is this using Laravel or wordpress? They are very different. If using Laravel, you have access to `Carbon` and `today()`, which simplifies things. `Carbon\Carbon::create('June 8, 2022')->diffInDays(today());`

Comment: it's on WordPress

Comment: Then DannyXCII 's solution should work for you

Answer (score 1):

The `get_the_date()` function should return a formatted date string, which you can pass in to PHP's `DateTime` class - [see the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

This includes a couple of handy methods to allow you to retrieve past/future dates which could prove useful here, particularly `DateTimeInterface::diff()` which returns the difference as an instance of `DateTimeInterval` - here's how you might use it in your code:

```
$postedAt = new DateTime(get_the_date());
$postedAtDiff = $postedAt->diff(new DateTime());
$postedAtString = $postedAtDiff->format('%a days ago');
```

You can then `echo` out the `$postedAtString` where you like.

Comment: Using `date_create`, this can be converted into a one liner.

Comment: `echo date_create(get_the_date())->diff(date_create())->format('%a days ago');`

Comment: @IGP good shout, or using `DateTime`: `echo (new DateTime(get_the_date()))->diff(new DateTime())->format('%a days ago');`, but neither of these are very readable for newer devs imo.